# How to handle shared lookup tables across tenant databases using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, multi-tenant

We're developing a multi-tenant application.  The design is such that each tenant will have their own database (on the same server) and each database will have the same schema.

The system has certain lookup tables that define values that will be constant across all systems.  For example, States, Counties, Genders, etc.  The design states that these will be in a "Control" database.  The "Control" database is managed by our organization -- so tenants can read data from the lookup tables but cannot write data to the tables.

The idea here is that we want to avoid duplicating these lookup tables and data in every database.  If we have to change a value or add a new value we can do it in one table as opposed to having to update it in each tenant database.

The problem is that with EF Core, we have two DbContexts -- one that ties to the tenant's data and one that ties to the Control database.  There doesn't seem to be a way to define cross-database relationships.

**example**

```
//Table exists in each Tenant Database
public class Client{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}

    //Table of Counties defined in "Control" database
    public int CountyOfResidenceId { get; set;}
    public County CountyOfResidence {get; set;}

}
```

The only way I can think of to handle this design is to have to (in my API Controller) validate id's coming from the client (via lookup to the Control database) and manually populating the `CountyOfResidence` (as well as all other "lookup" properties) for every client read from the database.

How is this generally handled by those creating Multi-Tenant applications where each tenant is required to have their own database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with DB-per-Tenant, I leverage replication to control lookup tables across tenant DBs. The issue with trying to centralize "common" tables in a separate database is that you lose the ability to efficiently enforce FK relationships. With SQL Server you can use check constraints across databases in place of FKs, but there is a performance cost to this, which IMO is *not* worth the relatively low cost of putting these tables in each tenant DB.  Given that these are supposed to be truly common tables, they shouldn't be expected to change very frequently, if at all. One-way replication is pretty dead-simple to set up or even manage manually as a schedule-able job.

The way I structure my multi-tenant applications is that the master DBContext/DB handles only authentication, versioning, maintenance tracking, and handing off the Tenant's DB connection string once authenticated.

Comment: Can you share details on how you achieved replication? Based on my research it doesn't appear to be dead simple. For example with Azure Data Sync there are limitations on how many dB's can be added to a sync group etc...

Comment: The one-way replication example for things like common lookup tables can be as simple as scheduled queries that generate insert/update statements to be run across all of the replicas.  In my case I had a system with just over 20 replicas and opted for tracking replication changes via an EF DbContext (against PostgreSQL) which recorded update instructions (table & row #) for a background job to replicate across all client DBs. This service also coordinated schema updates, so probably most similar to a SQL Statement type replication.